# How can I use endsWith() function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to run a foreach loop based on these array elements.

my array:

```
module_adlari: { 
    "bina-verisi": "Bina Okuma", 
    "bina-verisi:yazma": "Bina Düzenleme", 
    "parsel-verisi": "Parsel Okuma",
    "parsel-verisi:yazma": "Parsel Düzenleme", 
    "kira-verisi,gsm-verisi": "Kira Okuma", 
    "kira-verisi:yazma,gsm-verisi:yazma": "Kira Düzenleme", 
    "tapu-verisi":"Tapu Okuma", 
    "tapu-verisi:yazma":"Tapu Düzenleme", 
    "menu-degerleme-liste":"Değerleme Okuma",
    "menu-degerleme-liste:yazma":"Değerleme Düzenleme",
    "imar-verisi":"İmar Okuma", 
    "imar-verisi:yazma":"İmar Düzenleme", 
    "menu-raporlama":"Raporlama Okuma", 
    "menu-raporlama:yazma":"Raporlama Düzenleme", 
    "onaylama-bildirimi":"Onaylama Bildirimi Okuma",
    "onaylama-bildirimi:yazma":"Onaylama Bildirimi Düzenleme",
    "proje-sabitleri":"Proje Sabitleri Okuma",
    "proje-sabitleri:yazma":"Proje Sabitleri Düzenleme",
    "mevcut-durum":"Mevcut Durum Okuma",

},
```

and my codes:

```
if (!izinler.TASINMAZ_YONETICI) {
  for (var ad in Ayarlar.module_adlari) {
    if (!izinler[ad]) {
      var adlar = ad.split(",");
      adlar.forEach(function(a) {

        $("." + a)
          .parent()
          .remove();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I do not want to include the elements in the `module_adlari` array ending with `:yazma` into the `foreach` loop because it gives me an error like this =

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: yazma

Comment: That is not an array, that is an object. Also none of the items in that object contain `:write` so I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: Depening on your needs `if (ad.endsWith(":write"))` or `if (!ad.endsWith(":write"))` ??? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: Sorry, I wrote in English   will be   :yazma

Comment: The answer from derpirscher should then be what you're looking for

Comment: if (ad.endsWith(":yazma")) or if (!ad.endsWith(":yazma"))  yes this. But ı dont know where to use

Comment: Nothing matches, making your question meaningless!

Comment: which  if (ad.endsWith(":yazma")) or if (a.endsWith(":yazma")) ?  Where will it be written?

Comment: If you are simply wanting the object to only contains key/values where the key does not end with ":yamza"

You can use reduce:

`const filtered_module_adlari = Object.keys(module_adlari).reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (!key.endsWith(":yazma")) {
            acc[key] = module_adlari[key];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean you want to skip the ones that end with `:yazma`, since there are no `:write`. Just use a simple `if` statement.

```
adlar.forEach(function(a) {
  if (!a.endsWith(':yazma')) {
    $("." + a)
      .parent()
      .remove();
  }
});
```

You could be more general and filter out anything that contains `:`.

```
if (!a.includes(':'))
```